# No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed when installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, ssd, hp

I know there are a lot of other similar post about this issue but none of them have been helpful. Essentially I am trying to install Ubuntu Server on an old HP Computer from 2012. I installed it on the computer however it says `exiting intel pxe rom  no boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed`

Things I have tried:
So far I have tried changing the boot order and manually booting to the correct ssd both with no success. I have also verified that it has successfully installed on the ssd by booting to it from a different computer with success. I also reinstalled windows on it to see if there were any issues with that, which they are none.

The system has a Core I7 3770 and 12gb of ram with a 225GB SSD

I am assuming I have some bios setting wrong but none of the post I have seen have worked so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to disable the "Network Boot" option in your BIOS/UEFI. That is often the reason for a PXE error 

Comment: Product & release details are always helpful, you mention Ubuntu Server, but is that Ubuntu Server of *unstated* release, or Ubuntu Core *unstated* release as they are server products also... Did you verify the ISO? and then your write to installation media (*how this is done varies on your unstated release of unstated server product*) but user errors here will also result in the non-booting you mention.

Comment: @matigo i did that and now the PXE error is gone but the no boot disk is still there

Comment: is your harddrive detected in bios/uefi menue? is it set as 1. bootdevice there?

Comment: @nobody yes, as mentioned in my post i already checked that its the number one boot device and I have tried directly booting to it. I tried to boot of a different computer with that ssd and it worked, so its not the actual os itself.